# How to create docker compose file which installs prisma v5?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, prisma, prisma-graphql

I have this docker-compose.yml file. It uses prisma v1.12.
I want to create prisma docker with latest prisma.How to implement?

```
version: '3'
services:
  prisma:
    image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.12
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "4466:4466"
    environment:
      PRISMA_CONFIG: |
        port: 4466
        # uncomment the next line and provide the env var PRISMA_MANAGEMENT_API_SECRET=my-secret to activate cluster security
        # managementApiSecret: my-secret
        databases:
          default:
            connector: postgres
            host: ec2-50-16-241-91.compute-1.amazonaws.com
            port: '5432'
            database: d63k1orhak3ro8
            ssl: true
            user: ijgyrvqtpinnqe
            password: 45c5b8e5eb835c06d51150e5869b655590c01d0ace319ac6bb8e01cfa57f55b2
            migrations: true
```

I checked on docker hub,I think they have stopped creating prisma docker with latest version.
Should I create my own prisma docker and upload in docker hub?If yes,then how to implement that?

Comment: The old version 1.12 is included in the `image:` line.  What have you tried already?  What problems are you running into?

Answer (score 0):

`docker-compose` does not install anything: it *executes* existing images.
Since you don't have an image with Prima v5 you have to create it.  To create it you have to write a `Dockerfile`, not `docker-compose`.  Simply speaking, in the `Dockerfile` you have to put the same instructions that you would use to install Prisma on a Linux machine without Docker.  Do you know these instructions?  If not (like me!), you have to:

1. study Prisma documentation,
2. try a manual install,
3. and then put the instructions in the `Dockerfile` using the correct syntax.

An alternative is to search on Docker Hub to see if someone has created an unofficial image of Prisma v5.